# HITS Algorithm and Wikipedia

Tags: algorithm, graph

Please look at the following link: [HITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm)

I claim the pseudo code given is wrong. The problem is that it is defining a function called `HubsAndAuthorities` and the function is never called. I am thinking that the way to fix the algorithm is to delete line 5. This is line 5:

```
function HubsAndAuthorities(G)
```

Am I right? Is there something I am missing?

Here is the code from Wikipedia:

```
1 G := set of pages
 2 for each page p in G do
 3   p.auth = 1 // p.auth is the authority score of the page p
 4   p.hub = 1 // p.hub is the hub score of the page p
 5 function HubsAndAuthorities(G)
 6   for step from 1 to k do // run the algorithm for k steps
 7     norm = 0
 8     for each page p in G do  // update all authority values first
 9       p.auth = 0
10       for each page q in p.incomingNeighbors do // p.incomingNeighbors is the set of pages that link to p
11          p.auth += q.hub
12       norm += square(p.auth) // calculate the sum of the squared auth values to normalise
13     norm = sqrt(norm)
14     for each page p in G do  // update the auth scores 
15       p.auth = p.auth / norm  // normalise the auth values
16     norm = 0
17     for each page p in G do  // then update all hub values
18       p.hub = 0
19       for each page r in p.outgoingNeighbors do // p.outgoingNeighbors is the set of pages that p links to
20         p.hub += r.auth
21       norm += square(p.hub) // calculate the sum of the squared hub values to normalise
22     norm = sqrt(norm)
23     for each page p in G do  // then update all hub values
24       p.hub = p.hub / norm   // normalise the hub values
```

However, I feel it is best viewed on the Wikipedia page I posted a link to.

Comment: Post the code from wikipedia in your question please (with proper attribution).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. If you believe there's an error on the page, you should bring that up as a discussion on the page.